# C++ - place multiple images in an array pointer

Tags: c++, c, opengl

I have been trying to read ten images stored on the disk into an array pointer using the SOIL library. I would like to then render the resulting data in OpenGL using 3D textures.

The code I wrote to read images from the disk and store them in a buffer throws up `Access violation reading location 0x00000000` errors.

Is this the right way of storing multiple images using SOIL into an array pointer?

```
unsigned char *tex;
int imSize = h*w;

unsigned char *buff = new unsigned char[h * w * slices];

for(int i = 1; i<=10; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j<imSize; j++)
    { 
        if (i==1)
        {   
            tex = (unsigned char*) SOIL_load_OGL_texture("Data/PA_170090.png",
                    SOIL_LOAD_AUTO,SOIL_CREATE_NEW_ID,SOIL_FLAG_INVERT_Y);

            buff[((i-1)*imSize) + j] = tex[j]; }

        if (i==2)
        {   tex = (unsigned char*)SOIL_load_OGL_texture("Data/PA_170091.png",
                    SOIL_LOAD_AUTO,SOIL_CREATE_NEW_ID,  SOIL_FLAG_INVERT_Y);
            buff[(i-1)*imSize + j] =  tex[j]; }

        if (i==3)
        {   tex = (unsigned char*)SOIL_load_OGL_texture("Data/PA_170092.png",
                    SOIL_LOAD_AUTO,SOIL_CREATE_NEW_ID,  SOIL_FLAG_INVERT_Y);
            buff[(i-1)*imSize + j] =  tex[j];}

        ....
        .... // up to 10 images

    }
}
```

Comment: side note, put names of textures in array and get them by array index, why you work so hard ?

Comment: That's true. I was just working with the SOIL library and the documentation online provided a way of overwriting an existing variable/pointer. http://www.lonesock.net/soil.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems `SOIL_load_OGL_texture`, is not returning any buffer. Instead, it returns an Id (of type `GLuint` , which is `unsigned int`). If the function fails, the id will be zero. You are casting that integer value to a pointer  and dereferencing it, which results in access violation.

Comment: Interesting. I did not know that. I was under the assumption that this would directly load the image data to a pointer. 
Is there any way to load an image file into an array pointer? The code however looks reasonable right? I was under the impression that it might be wrong.

Comment: @Eagle Try using SOIL_load_image method to load the image to unsigned char*. http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Modern_OpenGL_Tutorial_06#Using_SOIL

Comment: @Eagle: Instead of concatenating the images into a large buffer you can instead use glTexSubImage3D to load the slices into a preallocated 3D texture slice by slice. Use `glTexImage3D(…, data=NULL)` to initialize the texture object with a default white texture image.