# OpenGL - 'glTexSubImage3D': identifier not found

Tags: c++, opengl

**Problem:** I've been trying to figure out this error in OpenGL that I keep getting with `glTexSubImage3D`. VS2010 throws the error: `glTexSubImage3D: identifier not found`

**Usage:** I am trying to create a 3D texture with ten slices (images) placed along the z-dimension. It is similar to the question in this post: [C++ - place multiple images in an array pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21472364/c-place-multiple-images-in-an-array-pointer)

However, I have been trying to use glTexSubImage3D in order to avoid these access violation errors.

I have included `glext.h` in my project and since, `glTexImage3D` is not part of OpenGL libraries yet, I have used the function pointer `PFNGLTEXIMAGE3DPROC glTexImage3D` as provided for use here: http://content.gpwiki.org/index.php/OpenGL:Tutorials:3D_Textures

**Code:**

I have been following NeHe's Texture Mapping tutorial and volume rendering tutorial present here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/352270/Getting-started-with-Volume-Rendering?msg=4729498

```
GLuint m_nTexId;            
unsigned char *tex;

int h = 1024;               
int w = 256;
int slices = 10;

PFNGLTEXIMAGE3DPROC glTexImage3D = (PFNGLTEXIMAGE3DPROC) wglGetProcAddress("glTexImage3D");

int LoadGLTextures()                                    
{
    glGenTextures(1,(GLuint*)&m_nTexId );

    if(m_nTexId == 0)
    return false;

    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_3D, m_nTexId );
    glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_REPLACE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);


    glTexImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0, GL_RGBA, w, h , slices, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL );

    tex = (unsigned char *)SOIL_load_image("Data/PA_170090.png", &w, &h, NULL, 0);
    glTexSubImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0, 0, 0, 0, h, w, 1, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (GLvoid*) tex);

    tex = (unsigned char*) SOIL_load_image("Data/PA_170091.png", &w, &h, NULL, 0);
    glTexSubImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0, 0, 0, 1, h, w, 1, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (GLvoid*) tex);

    tex = (unsigned char *)SOIL_load_image("Data/PA_170092.png", &w, &h, NULL, 0);
    glTexSubImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0, 0, 0, 2, h, w, 1, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (GLvoid*) tex);

    tex = (unsigned char *)SOIL_load_image("Data/PA_170093.png", &w, &h, NULL, 0);
    glTexSubImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0, 0, 0, 3, h, w, 1, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (GLvoid*) tex);

    tex = (unsigned char *)SOIL_load_image("Data/PA_170094.png", &w, &h, NULL, 0);
    glTexSubImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0, 0, 0, 4, h, w, 1, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (GLvoid*) tex);

    tex = (unsigned char *)SOIL_load_image("Data/PA_170095.png", &w, &h, NULL, 0);
    glTexSubImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0, 0, 0, 5, h, w, 1, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (GLvoid*) tex);

    tex = (unsigned char*) SOIL_load_image("Data/PA_170096.png", &w, &h, NULL, 0);
    glTexSubImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0, 0, 0, 6, h, w, 1, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (GLvoid*) tex);

    tex = (unsigned char*) SOIL_load_image("Data/PA_170097.png", &w, &h, NULL, 0);
    glTexSubImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0, 0, 0, 7, h, w, 1, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (GLvoid*) tex);

    tex = (unsigned char*) SOIL_load_image("Data/PA_170098.png", &w, &h, NULL, 0);
    glTexSubImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0, 0, 0, 8, h, w, 1, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (GLvoid*) tex);

    tex = (unsigned char*) SOIL_load_image("Data/PA_170099.png", &w, &h, NULL, 0);
    glTexSubImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0, 0, 0, 9, h, w, 1, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (GLvoid*) tex);
//glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0 );

    return true;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the same as you had when you originally tried to use `glTexImage3D (...)`. Namely, 3D textures are a feature of OpenGL 1.2 and Windows only gives you OpenGL 1.1 without run-time extension.

You need to load the `glTexSubImage3D (...)` function the same as you did `glTexImage3D (...)`.

```
PFNGLTEXSUBIMAGE3DPROC glTexSubImage3D =
 (PFNGLTEXSUBIMAGE3DPROC) wglGetProcAddress("glTexSubImage3D");
```

Comment: Darn, I had to use `PFNGLTEXSUBIMAGE3DPROC` instead of `PFNGLTEXIMAGE3DPROC` which was what I was trying all along! 
However, I still am getting access violation errors at `glTexImage3D() : 0xC0000005: Access violation.`

Comment: Does the size of the image slice that I am trying to load affect anything? Each image is 1024x256 and there are 10 such images.

Comment: After looking at the tutorial you followed, I can see why this was not clear. For completeness, you might as well also setup `PFNGLCOPYTEXSUBIMAGE3DPROC glCopyTexSubImage3D = (PFNGLCOPYTEXSUBIMAGE3DPROC) wglGetProcAddress("glCopyTexSubImage3D");`. There is one other thing you must know: you have to call this ***after*** you create your OpenGL window. You cannot setup those functions until you have a render context, and it must also be a hardware accelerated context, otherwise there will be no extension to load.

Comment: @Eagle: You also seem to have `w` and `h` transposed in your call to `glTexSubImage3D (...)`. That will make a difference.

Comment: I don't get it. Why would I need to use `glCopyTexSubImage()`? Also the flow of function calls in the NeHe tutorial inside `main()` proceeds like this: `CreateGLWindow()`, `InitGL()`, `LoadGLTextures()`, `DrawGLScene()`. So, if I understand you correctly, instead of placing all these `glTexSubImage3D` calls in `initGL()`, I should place them in `loadGLTextures()` right?

Comment: I don't think you would need to use `glCopyTexSubImage3D(...)`. The point I was trying to make is that 3D textures added those 3 functions to the API. Originally you only loaded one of the 3 functions and then you wound up with an issue later on because you were missing one of the other 2. To cover all bases when you use an extension, usually people load the entire thing... some libraries like GLEW take this to the extreme and load every function from every extension the system supports.

Comment: Regarding where you call `wglGetProcAddress (...)` from, as long as it is not at global scope like it looks like in your current question. The way your question is currently written, it is unclear exactly when `wglGetProcAddress` is being called - and it needs to happen ***after*** you create your GL context.

Comment: Right, that makes it clear. So, it would be towards my advantage if I use all three functions. Yes, you are right. I was globally calling `wglGetProcAddress`. I will call it after I set up the window and do the basic OpenGL function calls for setting up the rendering context, i.e., only after `CreateGLWindow()`, `InitGL()`, `LoadGLTextures()` are called. Thanks! :)