# OpenGL - render 3D texture

Tags: opengl

**Idea:** 
I have been trying to develop code which can take several (ten) slices of 2D images and render them as a 3D texture. I have so far used `glTexImage3D` and `glTexSubImage3D` upon suggestions from my previous post here: [OpenGL - 'glTexSubImage3D': identifier not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21506131/opengl-gltexsubimage3d-identifier-not-found)

I have been based my work off of NeHe's texture mapping tutorial here: http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/lesson_06_texturing_update/47002/

The flow of function calls in the NeHe's tutorial in `main()` proceeds like this: `CreateGLWindow()`, `InitGL()`, `LoadGLTextures()`, `DrawGLScene()`. I have only made changes to the code commencing upwards from `DrawGLScene()` while, everything below that function is the same as in my code.

**Problem:** 
Everything in the code *seemingly* looks right but, there is nothing being rendered on the screen. I have spent two days on this trying to get it to work to no avail. What am I missing? Is there something that I am doing incorrectly?

**EDITED CODE**

```
#include "windows.h"        
#include "stdio.h"          
#include "gl\gl.h"          
#include "gl\glu.h"         
#include "GLext.h"
#include "SOIL.h"

HDC          hDC=NULL;      
HGLRC        hRC=NULL;      
HWND         hWnd=NULL;     
HINSTANCE    hInstance;     

bool    keys[256];          
bool    active=TRUE;        
bool    fullscreen=TRUE;    

GLfloat xrot;               
GLfloat yrot;               
GLfloat zrot;               

GLuint  m_nTexId;           
unsigned char tex;

int h = 1024;           
int w = 256;
int slices = 10;

GLfloat dOrthoSize = 1.0f;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);   

// EDIT HERE

PFNGLTEXIMAGE3DPROC TexImage3D;
PFNGLTEXSUBIMAGE3DPROC TexSubImage3D;
PFNGLCOPYTEXSUBIMAGE3DPROC CopyTexSubImage3D;

int LoadGLTextures()    
{
    glGenTextures(1,(GLuint*)&m_nTexId );

    if(m_nTexId == 0)
    return false;

    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_3D, m_nTexId );
    glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_REPLACE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    return true;
}


GLvoid ReSizeGLScene(GLsizei width, GLsizei height)     
{
    if (height==0)                                      
    {
        height=1;
    }

    glViewport(0,0,width,height);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    gluPerspective(45.0f,(GLfloat)width/(GLfloat)height,0.1f,100.0f);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();   
}

int InitGL(GLvoid)  
{
    if (!LoadGLTextures())
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_3D);
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f);   
    glClearDepth(1.0f);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL); 
    glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);

// EDIT HERE

    TexImage3D = (PFNGLTEXIMAGE3DPROC) wglGetProcAddress("glTexImage3D");
    TexSubImage3D = (PFNGLTEXSUBIMAGE3DPROC) wglGetProcAddress("glTexSubImage3D");
    CopyTexSubImage3D = (PFNGLCOPYTEXSUBIMAGE3DPROC) wglGetProcAddress("glCopyTexSubImage3D");

    return TRUE;
}

#define MAP_3DTEXT( TexIndex ) \
    glTexCoord3f(0.0f, 0.0f, ((float)TexIndex+1.0f)/2.0f);  \
    glVertex3f(-dOrthoSize,-dOrthoSize,TexIndex);\
    glTexCoord3f(1.0f, 0.0f, ((float)TexIndex+1.0f)/2.0f);  \
    glVertex3f(dOrthoSize,-dOrthoSize,TexIndex);\
    glTexCoord3f(1.0f, 1.0f, ((float)TexIndex+1.0f)/2.0f);  \
    glVertex3f(dOrthoSize,dOrthoSize,TexIndex);\
    glTexCoord3f(0.0f, 1.0f, ((float)TexIndex+1.0f)/2.0f);  \
    glVertex3f(-dOrthoSize,dOrthoSize,TexIndex);


int DrawGLScene(GLvoid)
{
    PFNGLTEXIMAGE3DPROC glTexImage3D = (PFNGLTEXIMAGE3DPROC) wglGetProcAddress("glTexImage3D");
    PFNGLTEXSUBIMAGE3DPROC glTexSubImage3D = (PFNGLTEXSUBIMAGE3DPROC) wglGetProcAddress("glTexSubImage3D");
    PFNGLCOPYTEXSUBIMAGE3DPROC glCopyTexSubImage3D = (PFNGLCOPYTEXSUBIMAGE3DPROC) wglGetProcAddress("glCopyTexSubImage3D");

    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT  | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );

    //glEnable( GL_ALPHA_TEST );
    //glAlphaFunc( GL_GREATER, 0.2f );

    //glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    //glBlendFunc( GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA );

    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(0,0,-300,0,0,1,0,1,0);


    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_3D);
    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_3D,  m_nTexId );

    TexImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0, GL_RGBA, w, h , slices, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL );


    glTranslatef( 0.0f, 0.0f, 100.0f );


    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    tex = (unsigned char)SOIL_load_image("Data/PA_170090.png", &w, &h, NULL, 0);
    TexSubImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0, 0, 0, 1, w, h, 1, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (GLvoid*) tex);
    MAP_3DTEXT( 0.0f );
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    tex = (unsigned char) SOIL_load_image("Data/PA_170091.png", &w, &h, NULL, 0);
    TexSubImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0, 0, 0, 2, w, h, 1, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (GLvoid*) tex);
    MAP_3DTEXT( 0.1f );
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    tex = (unsigned char)SOIL_load_image("Data/PA_170092.png", &w, &h, NULL, 0);
    TexSubImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0, 0, 0, 3, w, h, 1, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (GLvoid*) tex);
    MAP_3DTEXT( 0.2f );
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    tex = (unsigned char)SOIL_load_image("Data/PA_170093.png", &w, &h, NULL, 0);
    TexSubImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0, 0, 0, 4, w, h, 1, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (GLvoid*) tex);
    MAP_3DTEXT( 0.3f );
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    tex = (unsigned char)SOIL_load_image("Data/PA_170094.png", &w, &h, NULL, 0);
    TexSubImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0, 0, 0, 5, w, h, 1, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (GLvoid*) tex);
    MAP_3DTEXT( 0.4f );
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    tex = (unsigned char)SOIL_load_image("Data/PA_170095.png", &w, &h, NULL, 0);
    TexSubImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0, 0, 0, 6, w, h, 1, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (GLvoid*) tex);
    MAP_3DTEXT( 0.5f );
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    tex = (unsigned char) SOIL_load_image("Data/PA_170096.png", &w, &h, NULL, 0);
    TexSubImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0, 0, 0, 7, w, h, 1, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (GLvoid*) tex);
    MAP_3DTEXT( 0.6f );
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    tex = (unsigned char) SOIL_load_image("Data/PA_170097.png", &w, &h, NULL, 0);
    TexSubImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0, 0, 0, 8, w, h, 1, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (GLvoid*) tex);
    MAP_3DTEXT( 0.7f );
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    tex = (unsigned char) SOIL_load_image("Data/PA_170098.png", &w, &h, NULL, 0);
    TexSubImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0, 0, 0, 9, w, h, 1, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (GLvoid*) tex);
    MAP_3DTEXT( 0.8f );
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    tex = (unsigned char) SOIL_load_image("Data/PA_170099.png", &w, &h, NULL, 0);
    TexSubImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0, 0, 0, 10, w, h, 1, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (GLvoid*) tex);
    MAP_3DTEXT( 0.9f );
    glEnd();

    return TRUE;

}
```

Comment: You should declare your `glTexImage3D`, etc. function pointers at a scope outside of your `DrawGLScene` function, and then load those pointers when you call `InitGL (...)`. There is no point in getting the function pointer from the driver every time you draw your scene, they are not going to change ever. Likewise, do your texture files change every frame? You probably want to load them only once if not... you are putting a lot of pressure on disk I/O currently.

Comment: But above all, I do not understand why you are transforming your texture matrix? You already provide the Z coordinate for your slice in the `MAP_3DTEXT(...)` macro. You should probably be transforming ModelView instead.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Yes, my frames change every second as I am trying to simulate a real-time system. Therefore, I need the hardware to be working all the time reloading an image. 
Please see my edits in the code in terms of declaring `PFNGLTEXIMAGE3DPROC` and associated pointers in global scope and defining the pointers in `InitGL()`.

Comment: Every second is different from every frame. You should periodically (every 1 second) reload the textures, and re-use the loaded image slices during the interim time. Also, your edit did not change a whole lot. You are shadowing the variables of the same name in `DrawGLScene (...)`.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Right, edited again. I will modify the code to work with the system every second later but, for now I'd like to stick with the example and see why it still doesn't work. My knowledge of 3D texture mapping is still evolving. Could you please tell me how I should transform the ModelView?

Comment: Replace `glMatrixMode (GL_TEXTURE)` with `glMatrixMode (GL_MODELVIEW)` and you should be done.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Thanks, but that still does not solve the problem unfortunately because I am still not able to see anything :/

Comment: You are probably clipping your quad by placing the camera at Z= **-300** and using a value of zFar= **100.0**. I would suggest you either remove the call to `glTranslatef (...)` or try setting your projection matrix's zFar to something like **1000.0** instead.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman That doesn't seem to work either :/
Here is the complete source code. I edited the code to work with only one image being rendered as a 3D texture. That still does not seem to work. http://pastebin.com/YpgVV4D0

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman How do I load the textures only once? I tried creating a new function to load the textures in `main()`, then in `loadGLTextures()`, then in global scope, but, it never worked. The texture keeps getting loaded with the same data all the time, causing the graphics I/O to work in overtime, and so I see nothing on the screen.

Comment: @Eagle: it is an error to call things like `glTexSubImage3D()` inside `glBegin()/glEnd()` blocks, so this can't work.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the function call TexSubImage3D, the argument depth is always 1, and you are incrementing only zoffset. Please keep the zoffset 0 and provide the depth/layer values from 8th argument (depth).

`TexSubImage3D( enum target, int level, int xoffset,
int yoffset, int zoffset, sizei width, sizei height,
sizei depth, enum format, enum type, const
void *data );`